# $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors in data.table inside a function in R

Tags: r, function, data.table

I am using an function:

```
if(nrow(product$productCC) > 0){

product$productCC$type

claimsInvoice[, CCtype := product$productCC$type]  
claimsInvoice[,  ':=' (CCtype = product$productCC$type)]   

}
```

but i both cases I get an error. I though by using ':=' was a functional form?

```
> product$productCC$type
[1] "GENERAL_CAP_PER_YEAR"
> claimsInvoice[, CCtype := product$productCC$type] 
Error in product$productCC : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

How can this be fixed?

EDIT:

i tried using

```
type <- product$productCC$type
claimsInvoice[,  ':=' (CCtype = type)]
```

instead of

```
claimsInvoice[, CCtype := product$productCC$type]
```

to avoid the scoping issues as mentioned by @chinsoon12, 
but that results in another error :

```
Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(claimsInvoice, , `:=`(CCtype = type)) :
  Coercing 'character' RHS to 'logical' to match the type of the target column (column 13 named 'CCtype').
```

Comment: interesting. does claimsInvoice has a column called product?

Comment: yes `> names(claimsInvoice[,5])
[1] "product"`

Comment: can you either rename the column or your variable `product`? as this is a scoping issue, columns in claimsInvoice are used first before variables in global env. i.e. `product` within the sq brackets is actually the column `product` in claimsInvoice which is a vector and accessing using `$` causes that error and not the list in your global env

Comment: ah ok, see the edit, is that something i could use?

Comment: What is `class(product$productCC)` and `class(product$productCC$type)`

Comment: `class(product$productCC)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"` and  `class(product$productCC$type)
[1] "character"`

Comment: maybe something like `claimsInvoice[, CCtype := as.character(CCtype)][,  CCtype := type]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue (I think) is the NSE evaluation of values, compounded by the convenience that `data.table::[` operations tend to give the user. One way to step around it is to the `set`, which is both simpler (no NSE) and at times faster than `data.table::[` and its `:=` assignment.

```r
claimsInvoice <- data.table(x = 1, product = 2)
product <- list(productCC = list(type = "GENERAL_CAP_PER_YEAR"))

### no surprise
claimsInvoice[, CCtype := product$productCC$type ]
# Error in product$productCC : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
### works
set(claimsInvoice, j = "CCtype", value = product$productCC$type)

claimsInvoice
#    x product               CCtype
# 1: 1       2 GENERAL_CAP_PER_YEAR
str(claimsInvoice)
# Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':    1 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ x      : num 1
#  $ product: num 2
#  $ CCtype : chr "GENERAL_CAP_PER_YEAR"
#  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```